# Woocommerce numeral in slug

Tags: woocommerce

I'm not versed in Woocommerce and hoping I can get some direction here. I've recently taken over a website at work, the previous guy sets up the following category structure:

> iphone-pro-cases
> iphone-pro-cases-2
> samsung-galaxy-cases
> samsung-galaxy-cases-2

Let's say on */product-category/iphone-pro-cases* page, I'm expecting to see only products of *iphone-pro-cases* on the page of *iphone-pro-cases*. However, it displays all products of *iphone-pro-cases* **and** *iphone-pro-cases-2*. Same goes to samsung-galaxy-cases. In *samsung-galaxy-cases* product category page, it displays products from both *samsung-galaxy-cases* **and** *samsung-galaxy-cases-2*.

Is this a default behaviour? Is the appending numeral in slug ignored?

Answer (score 0):

They should behave like completely separate categories. Much like categories associated with posts.

Might be worth it to try and flush the permalinks by going to:
Settings -> Permalinks
and clicking save.

Hopefully, that does the trick.